# Exclude certain directory names

Tags: vb.net, file-io, directory, contains, directoryinfo

How to exclude certain directory names when getting them from a directory?
I currently have:

```
Dim dir1 As DirectoryInfo() = dir2.GetDirectories()
```

I've tried a variation of the example below:

```
Dim dir1 As DirectoryInfo() = dir2.GetDirectories().Where(Name = Name.Contains("00000000.001"))
```

Trying to exclude two files names from a process I am going to be running on the rest of the files. Any suggestions would be great. Thanks!

EDIT:
Tested Answer provided by Tim using this code:

```
Dim direct1 As DirectoryInfo
For Each direct1 In dir1
        ListBox2.Items.Add(direct1.Name)
Next
```

It displayed the two file names that I am currently trying to avoid.

Comment: So you want to take or exlude all dirs which don't have 00000000.001 in their names?

Comment: I want to exclude all directories with  00000000.001 &  00000000.002 in their names

Comment: i have edited my answer below to include both cases.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll accept the answer when it lets me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use LINQ, therefore i would prefer [`DirectoryInfo.EnumerateDirectories`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413235(v=vs.110).aspx).

From MSDN:

> The `EnumerateDirectories` and `GetDirectories` methods differ as
>   follows: When you use `EnumerateDirectories`, you can start
>   enumerating the collection of `DirectoryInfo` objects before the whole
>   collection is returned. When you use `GetDirectories`, you must wait
>   for the whole array of `DirectoryInfo` objects to be returned before
>   you can access the array.

For example:

```
Dim dirs As DirectoryInfo() = dir2.EnumerateDirectories().
    Where(Function(dir) dir.Name.Contains("00000000.001")).
    ToArray()
```

If you instead want to exlude them use `Not ...`:

```
Dim dirs As DirectoryInfo() = dir2.EnumerateDirectories().
    Where(Function(dir) Not dir.Name.Contains("00000000.001")).
    ToArray()
```

If you want to exlude multiple use:

```
Dim exclude = { "00000000.001", "00000000.002" }

Dim dirs As DirectoryInfo() = dir2.EnumerateDirectories().
    Where(Function(dir) Not exclude.Any(Function(d) dir.Name.Contains(d))).
    ToArray()
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to have worked, I've edited my original post to show the code that I ran, and it still displayed the file directories that were suppose to have been excluded

Comment: @Pezzy007: but the code that you have edited does not use my LINQ approach. You are just enumerating all directories in the `For Each`. Replace `For Each direct1 In dir1` with `For Each direct1 In dirs` while `dirs` is what i have posted above as second approach.

Comment: So the `DirectoryInfo()` still contains directories which name contains `"00000000.001"`, can you show an example?

Comment: Hi Tim, sorry I have been away on holiday. I get the error message "Additional information: An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: Public member 'Any' on type 'String()' not found." When trying to exclude multiple directories from the search.

Comment: @Pezzy007: If you can't use LINQ methods like `Enumerable.Any` then you either use an old framework/visual studio(like 2005) or you don't have `Imports System.Linq`. Which vs version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and have Imports System.Linq at the top

Comment: Restarted the program and it works now. Thanks for all your help Tim! Would vote up your response but don't have 15 reputation yet.